# Grub Issue with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So I have an ASUS FX-503VD which has a 128GB SSD + 1TB HDD. During the initial installation of Ubuntu 19.04, I faced a few issues and decided to reinstall it. Now I'm facing a few problems:

1. The UEFI menu which appears on pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> has 2 Ubuntu entries, one on my HDD, and the other on my SSD. Whichever I choose, Ubuntu boots in the same way
2. I'm not able to view my Windows HDD partition (D:) through Ubuntu but I'm able to see the C:(SSD)
3. If I switch to Windows and then shut my laptop down, the next time I turn it on GRUB appears in command line (*Minimal Bash Like Grub....*), but if I restart using Windows (not shut down and start), GRUB appears normally. If I use Ubuntu, whether I shut down or restart, GRUB appears normally.

Both the times I installed Ubuntu identically and I let it install automatically.

One solution that was suggested was to run boot-repair. When I ran it, the option of Windows disappeared from my GRUB menu. To solve it I had typed the command `sudo os prober` (and something else I can't remember). Also now my GRUB menu has some additional options and I do not know what they are.

PS: I have provided the output of `lsblk` below

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 118.2G  0 part /media/anuraag/OS
└─sda4   8:4    0   800M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 736.2G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   127M  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 194.7G  0 part /
```

Comment: We don't know about your partitions. Please edit and add to your post the output of this command: lsblk

Comment: I've edited and uploaded the output.

Comment: for 2. Try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Please run `lsblk | grep -v loop` to filter out all your Snaps. Copy the result from that. Then, please click [edit] and paste the result into your question, so we get the result in plaintext instead of a linked image.

Comment: @MelcomX I tried it but it still doesn't show, it only shows my SSD inside the other locations section and it is name as OS, and the 200 GB I allocated for Ubuntu is shown as Computer.

Comment: Also I am not sure but could this be the reason for (2) : When I opened disk management in Windows, there is a 500 MB EFI file system that separates my 700GB windows partition(HDD) and the 200 that i allocated for Ubuntu. Would this prevent the windows partition from appearing in my Ubuntu?